# Delegation of trait impl only possible in nightly?

Tags: rust, traits

I want to delegate the implementation of the trait `Foo` to the contents of a (single element) container `Bar`, only when its generic contents already implements `Foo` (`Bar<T: Foo>`).

```
pub trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> u8;
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialOrd, Ord, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct Bar<T> {
    wrapped: T
}

impl Foo for Bar<T: Foo> {
    fn foo(&self) -> u8 {
        self.wrapped.foo()
    }
}
```

results in:

```
error[E0658]: associated type bounds are unstable
  --> /home/fadedbee/test.rs:26:18
   |
26 | impl Foo for Bar<T: Foo> {
   |                  ^^^^^^
   |
   = note: see issue #52662 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(associated_type_bounds)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

Is this only possible in nightly, or am I just using the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor syntactic difference.

```
impl<T : Foo> Foo for Bar<T> {
  fn foo(&self) -> u8 {
    self.wrapped.foo()
  }
}
```

The `impl` needs to introduce the type variable and then we *use* it in `Bar`. The above is equivalent to the more verbose

```
impl<T> Foo for Bar<T> where T : Foo {
  fn foo(&self) -> u8 {
    self.wrapped.foo()
  }
}
```

In either case, the `impl` introduces the type variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the error message was a little confusing.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the compiler was trying to parse the code as some advanced syntax sugar that I'm not familiar with. Had the feature not been nightly, it probably would've failed with a type error later on.